# Google charts setColumns not behaving right

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have been trying to use Google charts to display some data related to scuba diving (Not using actual data in the code below. Actual data is very huge). The data displays correctly when the page loads. But when I use check boxes to setColumns (to hide or show columns) the result is weird. The chart will hide wrong columns.

I have attached the code. If you run it you will see the data being displayed correctly. But when you will try to toggle any column on and off using the checkboxes you will realize that it hides / shows the wrong columns. (except for the first column)

```js
// load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        // this new DataTable object holds all the data
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(

            [
                ["Time", "10 Feet", "15 Feet", "20 Feet", "25 Feet", "30 Feet", "35 Feet"],
                ["5min", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                ["7min", 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
                ["8min", 1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
            ]
        );

        // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        // set chart options
        var options = {
            title: 'No Decompression Limits',
            vAxis: {
                title: 'GROUP DESIGNATOIN',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    color: '#333'
                },
                ticks: [{
                    v: 1,
                    f: 'A (1)'
                }, {
                    v: 2,
                    f: 'B (2)'
                }, {
                    v: 3,
                    f: 'C (3)'
                }, {
                    v: 4,
                    f: 'D (4)'
                }, {
                    v: 5,
                    f: 'E (5)'
                }, {
                    v: 6,
                    f: 'F (6)'
                }, {
                    v: 7,
                    f: 'G (7)'
                }, {
                    v: 8,
                    f: 'H (8)'
                }, {
                    v: 9,
                    f: 'I (9)'
                }, {
                    v: 10,
                    f: 'J (10)'
                }, {
                    v: 11,
                    f: 'K (11)'
                }, {
                    v: 12,
                    f: 'L (12)'
                }, {
                    v: 13,
                    f: 'M (13)'
                }, {
                    v: 14,
                    f: 'N (14)'
                }, {
                    v: 15,
                    f: 'O (15)'
                }, {
                    v: 16,
                    f: 'Decompress'
                }]
            },
            hAxis: {
                title: 'TIME (mins)',
                minValue: 10,
                direction: 1,
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 14
                },
                scaleType: 'log'
            },
            orientation: 'horizontal',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        $('.depth').change(function() {
            var depthArray = [];
            for (i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
                if ($(".depth:eq(" + (i) + ")").is(":checked")) {
                    depthArray.push(i);
                }
            }
            //console.log(depthArray);
            view.setColumns(depthArray);
            chart.draw(view, options);
        });

    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
        <h3>See No-Decompression Limits For Depths</h3>
        <div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox10" value=1>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;10 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox15" value=2>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;15 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox20" value=3>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;20 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox25" value=4>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;25 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox30" value=5>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;30 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox35" value=6>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;35 feet</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first column in the view (0) should always be the x-axis.
so you need to increase the index of the checked boxes by 1,
as the index of the first y-axis column is 1.

```
var depthArray = [0];
for (i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
    if ($(".depth:eq(" + (i) + ")").is(":checked")) {
        depthArray.push(i+1);
    }
}
```

but I would like to recommend a slightly different approach.

when the column should not be visible,
we use a calculated column that returns nothing,
and set the series color to grey.
the line still disappears, but the legend entry remains and appears "greyed out".
this will prevent the legend entries from "jumping",
and the color of each line from changing,
every time a box is checked / unchecked.

see following working snippet...

```js
// load the visualization library from Google and set a listener
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
    });
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        // this new DataTable object holds all the data
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(

            [
                ["Time", "10 Feet", "15 Feet", "20 Feet", "25 Feet", "30 Feet", "35 Feet"],
                ["5min", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                ["7min", 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10],
                ["8min", 1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
            ]
        );

        // this view can select a subset of the data at a time
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        // set chart options
        var options = {
            title: 'No Decompression Limits',
            vAxis: {
                title: 'GROUP DESIGNATOIN',
                titleTextStyle: {
                    color: '#333'
                },
                ticks: [{
                    v: 1,
                    f: 'A (1)'
                }, {
                    v: 2,
                    f: 'B (2)'
                }, {
                    v: 3,
                    f: 'C (3)'
                }, {
                    v: 4,
                    f: 'D (4)'
                }, {
                    v: 5,
                    f: 'E (5)'
                }, {
                    v: 6,
                    f: 'F (6)'
                }, {
                    v: 7,
                    f: 'G (7)'
                }, {
                    v: 8,
                    f: 'H (8)'
                }, {
                    v: 9,
                    f: 'I (9)'
                }, {
                    v: 10,
                    f: 'J (10)'
                }, {
                    v: 11,
                    f: 'K (11)'
                }, {
                    v: 12,
                    f: 'L (12)'
                }, {
                    v: 13,
                    f: 'M (13)'
                }, {
                    v: 14,
                    f: 'N (14)'
                }, {
                    v: 15,
                    f: 'O (15)'
                }, {
                    v: 16,
                    f: 'Decompress'
                }]
            },
            hAxis: {
                title: 'TIME (mins)',
                minValue: 10,
                direction: 1,
                textStyle: {
                    fontSize: 14
                },
                scaleType: 'log'
            },
            orientation: 'horizontal',
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

        $('.depth').change(function() {
            options.series = {};
            var depthArray = [0];
            $.each(new Array(data.getNumberOfColumns() - 1), function (i) {
                if ($(".depth:eq(" + (i) + ")").is(":checked")) {
                    depthArray.push(i+1);
                } else {
                    depthArray.push({
                      label: data.getColumnLabel(i+1),
                      type: data.getColumnType(i+1),
                      calc: function () {
                        return null;
                      },
                    });
                    
                    options.series[i] = {
                      color: '#cccccc'
                    };
                }
            });
            view.setColumns(depthArray);
            chart.draw(view, options);
        });

    };
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.csv.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 400px;"></div>
        <h3>See No-Decompression Limits For Depths</h3>
        <div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox10" value=1>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;10 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox15" value=2>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;15 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox20" value=3>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;20 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox25" value=4>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;25 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox30" value=5>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;30 feet</label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
                <input class="form-check-input depth" type="checkbox" checked id="inlineCheckbox35" value=6>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">&#8804;35 feet</label>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. And yes I will be using your approach it is much better.